# How to bind LINQ result to datagrid

Tags: c#, linq

i bind linq result data to datagrid but nothing comes. here is my code

```
        List<SearchResult> list = new List<SearchResult>() {
        new SearchResult(){ID=1,Title="Geo Prism 1995 GEO* - ABS #16213899"},
        new SearchResult(){ID=2,Title="Excavator JCB - ECU P/N: 728/35700"},
        new SearchResult(){ID=3,Title="Geo Prism GEO 1995 - ABS #16213899"},
        new SearchResult(){ID=4,Title="JCB Excavator JCB- ECU P/N: 728/35700"},
        new SearchResult(){ID=5,Title="Geo Prism GEO,GEO 1995 - ABS #16213899 GEO"},
        new SearchResult(){ID=6,Title="dog"},
        };

        var to_search = new[] { "Geo", "JCB" }.Select(x => x.ToLower()).ToArray();
        var result = from searchResult in list
                     let title = searchResult.Title.ToLower()
                     let key_string = to_search.FirstOrDefault(ts => title.Contains(ts))
                     orderby key_string == null ? -1 : title.Split(new[] { key_string }, StringSplitOptions.None).Length descending
                     group searchResult by key_string into Group
                     orderby Group.Count() descending
                     select Group;

        dataGridView2.DataSource = result;
```

when i run the above code datagrid showing nothing but i was expecting datagrid should show **ID and Title**

then i add some more line like

```
List<SearchResult> listFinal = new List<SearchResult>();
foreach (var group in result)
{
     foreach (var item in group)
     {
        listFinal.Add(new SearchResult() { ID = item.ID, Title = item.Title });
     }
 }
 dataGridView2.DataSource = listFinal;
```

now datagrid is showing data. so my question is that....is there any short cut way to convert result to list as a result i can bind list directly to datagrid with iterate in loop and create a new list and fill it up before binding. looking for guidance. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just call [.SelectMany()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) and [.ToList()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) on your LINQ query.

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = result.SelectMany(e => e).ToList();
```

or create your List with the [appropriate constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0):

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = new List(result.SelectMany(e => e));
```

Comment: data is showing as a group of data. so one geo and one jcb is showing. so all ID and title are not showing . that is why i need to iterate in data and add all details in loop in another list. show me some shortest way to bind data like all ID & title to grid??

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
   var result = (from searchResult in list
                         let title = searchResult.Title.ToLower()
                         let key_string = to_search.FirstOrDefault(ts => title.Contains(ts))
                         orderby key_string == null ? -1 : title.Split(new[] { key_string }, StringSplitOptions.None).Length descending
                         group searchResult by key_string into Group
                         orderby Group.Count() descending
                         select Group).ToList();
```

Comment: data is showing as a group of data. so one geo and one jcb is showing. so all ID and title are not showing . that is why i need to iterate in data and add all details in loop in another list. show me some shortest way to bind data like all ID & title to grid??